# Set variable in loop

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to create a json object on twig, so I need to set a variable inside a loop.
After many attempts I found this way, but it's fine when I only have two records, if I have any more you generate the problem:

```
{% set data = [] %}
{% for artist in artists %}
     {% if loop.first %}
         {%
         set data = {
               id        : artist.id,
               text      : artist.name|capitalize() ~' '~ artist.surname|capitalize()
             }
         %}
     {% else %}
         {%
          set data = [data,{
              id        : artist.id,
              text      : artist.name|capitalize() ~' '~ artist.surname|capitalize()
            }]
         %}
     {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 {% set data = {results: data} %}
 {{ data|json_encode|raw }}
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
{results: [{id: 1, text: "bla"},{id: 2, text: "blabla"},{id: 3, text: "blablabla"}]}
```

Instead I get:

```
{results:[[{id:1,text:"bla"},{id:2,text:"blabla"}],{id:3,text:"blablabla"}]}
```

Is there a way to build a json object inside twig without going crazy?

I've already tried this way .. but rewrites the object and saves in the variable only the last element:

```
{% set data = [] %}
{% for artist in artists %}
     {%
      set data = {
          id        : artist.id,
          text      : artist.name|capitalize() ~' '~ artist.surname|capitalize()
        }
     %}
{% endfor %}
{% set data = {results: data} %}
{{ data|json_encode|raw }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [merge](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html).

```
{% set data = [] %}
{% for artist in artists %}
     {%
      set data = data|merge ([{
          id        : artist.id,
          text      : artist.name|capitalize() ~' '~ artist.surname|capitalize()
        }])
     %}
{% endfor %}
{% set data = {results: data} %}
{{ data|json_encode|raw }}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Working up at 5 am makes bad jokes!